# Installing Node.JS and Socket.IO in Joomla

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to develop a simple chat for my website, I tried with ajax first but then I was recommended to develop it using Socket.IO instead, I saw their demo and everything looks great, I have my website and server all set up with cPanel, the only issue I have is getting started, looking at their documentation it seems I need to install node.js first and then I can run Socket.IO. Could you give me some guidance?

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.

Comment: Please be aware that this question will probably be closed as there is far too much to cover to answer your question. 
As it is, I've not seen anything recent, but you could check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712648/does-drupal-or-joomla-allow-a-combination-node-js-and-socket-io-with-php and https://github.com/jlleblanc/nodejs-joomla 
Unrelated to node and socket, but as an alternative you could try using something like nginx's Nchan- https://github.com/slact/nchan

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I'd find out from your host if you can even SSH into your server to install Node.js first. Most shared hosts won't allow this. But if they do, may be best to follow a guide for a chat system of your choice, and then embed it on your site via an iframe.